# Rails 4 - Assigning values for a row in an associated table in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Beginner of rails here, for my project I need to create a client with things such as first name, middle name, last name and their passport. I have another table called passports that will store the passport. I want to be able to add a passport number in association with the client. Here are the relevant pieces of code:

Controller for Client

```
def new
  @client = Client.new
end
def create
  @client = Client.new(client_params)
  if @client.save
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
  def client_params
    params.require(:client).permit(:firstname, :middlename, :lastname, :PresentAddress)
  end
end
```

Controller for Passport

```
def new
    @passport = Passport.new
end
def create
    passport = Passport.new(passport_params)
    if @passport.save
        flash[:notice] = "Passport saved"
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Passport not saved"
    end
end
private
    def passport_params
        params.require(:passport).permit(:idnumber, :country)
    end
end
```

Model for Client

```
has_one :passport, foreign_key: "client_id"
```

Model for Passport

```
belongs_to :client
```

Migration file for client

```
create_table :clients do |t|
  t.string :firstname
  t.string :middlename
  t.string :lastname
end
```

Migration file for passport

```
create_table :passport do |t|
  t.string :passport
end
```

/clients/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@client) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :"First Name"%>
  <%= f.text_field :firstname%>
  <%= f.label :"Middle Name"%>
  <%= f.text_field :middlename%>
  <%= f.label :"Last Name"%>
  <%= f.text_field :lastname%>
<%= f.submit "Create Client" %>
<% end %>
```

/passport/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@client, @client.passport.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :"Passport ID Number" %>
    <%= f.text_field :idnumber %>
    <% f.submit "Create Passport" %>
<% end %>
```

/clients/new.html.erb

```
<%= render "clients/form" %>
<%= render "passports/new" %>
```

I want to be able to create a passport for the client in this form and send it to my Postgres database. How would I go about doing that? Please let me know if I'm missing any other information.

**EDIT** - changed to a field that's more simple for now. Also modified to do what ChiefrockaChris suggested.

Comment: First of all you shouldn't capitalize your attribute names.`:FirstName, :MiddleName` should be `:first_name, :middle_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this would be to put your #_form.html.erb view for addresses under your address views folder and then to render it as a partial in your client#create, client#update etc. view.  So for example:

```
#clients/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@client) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :"First Name"%>
  <%= f.text_field :FirstName%>
  <%= f.label :"Middle Name"%>
  <%= f.text_field :MiddleName%>
  <%= f.label :"Last Name"%>
  <%= f.text_field :LastName%>
  <%= f.label :"Present address"%>
  <%= f.text_field :PresentAddress %>
<%= f.submit "Create Client" %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your address views folder

```
#addresses/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for ([@client, @client.addresses.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :"Street Name"%>
  <%= f.text_field :street_name%>
<%= f.submit "Create Address" %>
<% end %>
```

Then on client#new:

```
#client/new.html.erb
<%= render "clients/form" %>
<%= render "addresses/form" %>
```

Also be sure that there is something in your address#create method that will reference the user creating so it saves in the database as such.
Also please do not capitalize your attribute names.

Comment: Can you explain to me the part @client.addresses.build does please?

Comment: So it basically creates the address as belonging to the client. It's called a nested form. See the rails guides here for more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Comment: I think I'm doing it correctly, but I've run into a "No association found for name `addresses'. Has it been defined yet?" error, thoughts? I added in the line "accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses". Prior to that it was still giving me an error like address isn't defined in Client.

Comment: Can you post your addresses controller?

Comment: Oh I actually didn't have a controller for addresses. So the only thing that would go in there would be a function like new and create that would accept params? Also since I plan to have many other things such as credit card info, would I need a controller for each of these attributes?

Comment: You definitely need a controller for them if they are a different table/model than users and it will need a new/create/update etc . As for credit cards etc, if they are different tables then yes you would need separate controllers for them. Unless you have a reason for keeping the addresses/creditcard info etc. as a different model it would probably be wiser to just include them in the user table. You can run a migration for that and then just add it to your client form and params.

Comment: Also what's with PresentAddress and Address. Do you not have a model for addresses?  If you want the user to have a collection of addresses and designate one of them a present address then I would make a model and controller for addresses and put in a binary field for :present_address.

Comment: Hey, I updated the main post, sorry for making you run around in circles, but this field is much more simple at the moment. I get an error for "undefined method `build' for nil:NilClas"

Comment: Try it plural so @client.passports.build